# Ionic 5 ion-slides as “Virtual Slides”

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides

I'm using [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/) v5 with [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) which are based on [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) which has a [`virtual` property](https://swiperjs.com/api/#virtual) that intelligently loads and unloads data from the DOM based on where in a list of items you are.

I can't find any information about how this would be implemented in Ionic though.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ion-slides` has an [`options` property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#properties) which you can use to pass additional parameters to Swiper.

The second option is to use Swiper directly. I've had to do that in the past because of problems with some custom options.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried that but the options didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Looks like `ion-slides` [only loads a subset of Swiper's features](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/slides/swiper/swiper.js#L3). Not sure if you can load more, otherwise you might have to use Swiper directly.

Comment: Well found.  That explains it then.  Thanks.  I'll explore using Swiper directly then.  Much appreciated.